# specify multiple variations for field in database using factory boy

Tags: django, factory-boy

I am new to using the tool django factory boy.
I would like to know how can we specify multiple test data patterns for a field in database model using the factory class of django factory boy.

For eg :Username is a field in the table users,
username can have variations like abc_123,abc123.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FactoryBoy provides a few options for this:

- Using the hook to the [Faker](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library, which includes rules to generate realistic values for common fields. Calling `factory.Faker('user_name')` will provide, for instance: `bmiller`, `ogarcia`, `alee`;
- The [`factory.fuzzy`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fuzzy.html) module provides some helpers for (managed) random generation. Calling `factory.fuzzy.FuzzyText(prefix='abc_')` would generate `abc_aCybLgKHOpdI` or `abc_pCaddoWBZbEO`;
- You may design your own fuzzy generator, inspired on the code in `factory/fuzzy.py`;
- You could build the usernames from the `sequence` counter provided to [`factory.Sequence`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#sequence)

Comment: Can I specify a list of patterns for a field like username  with factory.fuzzy.FuzzyText(prefix='abc_') ,factory.Faker('username')

Comment: List of patterns no, list of values are available with `factory.Iterator`. But you could write your own fuzzer, look at the source in `factory/fuzzy.py`!